# USB memory stick stopped working

Tags: mac, usb

My USB memory stick that I have had for 5 years now, stopped working out of the blue. I have tried it in different computers nothing shows up. The light in the USB memory stick used to blink once I inserted it into the PC, but now it does not.

Is there any way I can find out what is wrong with it? I am on `OS X` and the USB is on `FAT32`.

Comment: If it used to light up and doesn't even do that anymore, it's done for. If it's 5 years old it will cost next to nothing to replace.

Comment: If you don't know of any reason it would stop working, my bet is the USB connector got physically damaged -- the connections crack easily. It can probably be repaired with a soldering iron, but is likely not worth it.

Comment: Yes you guys are right, it cost me something like USD 200, it is 32GB. Thats why I was finding out if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: I hope that was a typo...did it really cost $200 for 32 gigs 5 years ago? You can [get a terabyte](http://www.amazon.com/Transcend-USB-External-Hard-Drive/dp/B005MNGQ6C/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1394843022&sr=8-1&keywords=terabyte) for less than that now!

Comment: I am afraid not. Adjusting the inflation rate, for the 32GB USB it was ~180-190 USD at the time.

Comment: Well, you can get one for under $20 now.  It's just not worth it to muck with the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, if it doesn't light up, chances are it's busted. If you can test it on a non-OS X device just to make sure, that might be worthwhile, but more likely than not the circuitry is just damaged. On the bright side, a replacement for your $200 USB now only costs $10-15, or $25 for a fancy USB 3.0 one.

If you have critical data on the drive, the actual flash storage itself might be functional, so you could follow [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Repair-a-USB-Flash-Drive) Wikihow article to try to get it back, or just take the drive in to a hardware repair store.